# Is there a way to indicate file & line differences —between specific branches— in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I really find the git indicators (a) in the gutter for each file (image 1 below) and (b) next to the filenames in the explorer sidebar (image 2 below) extremely beneficial.

Unfortunately, I find them so useful in getting the big picture of changes per feature branch, that I don't make commits as often as I should, because then I lose these indicators .

Obviously there's `git diff`, but that really isn't the same as having the inline indicators or, in the case of the gutter indicators, the inline indicators with the ability to quickly see what the difference is in situ.

I've looked for settings and extensions that would enable this, but to no avail.

So my question is whether it's possible to, and if so how to, have comparable indicators for git differences *between branches*; e.g. instead of indicators for differences between my current working state and the *most recent commit on my current branch*, have it display the indicators for the difference between my current working state and *the `main` or `master` branch*?

image 1: **git indicators in gutter** [image: git indicators in gutter]

image 2: **git indicators in Explorer** [image: git indicators in Explorer]

Comment: using GitLens you can setup a diff of the Working file to any commit, these diffs are life and you can edit the Working version, you can change the diff colors to make them less obvious

Comment: rioV8 - I've definitely used the GitLens diff view in the past (although, I hadn't realized that the current code could be edited - TIL) and I've also tried using their gutter heatmap.  Unfortunately, for me at least, the diff view makes it noticeably harder to work in the current code, and the heatmap doesn't have the type of precision that I'm looking for.  However, I really do appreciate your alternative approach suggestion!